# SQL SELECT substring using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING('Message-ID=<6aasd2k4081-f6asdasc134-43asd45c-b2asd32429-a32ad410de78@comunic.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results',
    (SELECT CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<','Message-ID=<6aasd2k4081-f6asdasc134-43asd45c-b2asd32429-a32ad410de78@comunic.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results') +1),
CHARINDEX('>, Authentication-Results', 'Message-ID=<6aasd2k4081-f6asdasc134-43asd45c-b2asd32429-a32ad410de78@comunic.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results') 
-CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<','Message-ID=<6aasd2k4081-f6asdasc134-43asd45c-b2asd32429-a32ad410de78@comunic.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results') -1)
```

This works just fine when I run it (no errors).

I am trying to do the same thing but now using a variable which has the value returned from a select statement:

```
DECLARE @itemProp nvarchar(max);
set @itemProp=  (SELECT ItemProperties FROM [table1] where colID=1)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@itemProp,
(SELECT CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<',@itemProp) +1),
CHARINDEX('>, Authentication-Results', @itemProp) 
-CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<',@itemProp) -1)
```

When I run this query, I get the following error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.

The value of the `@itemProp` assigned by the select statement is same as in the first example:

```
'Message-ID=<6aasd2k4081-f6asdasc134-43asd45c-b2asd32429-a32ad410de78@comunic.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results'.
```

Also, I am using SQL Server 2005.

Any help is appreciated - thanks

Comment: If subquery returns 0 you will have 0-1 (=-1) - zero or negative length.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is looking for `' Message-ID=<'`, with a space at the beginning.  That doesn't seem to be in the string.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@itemProp,
                 CHARINDEX('Message-ID=<', @itemProp) +1,
----------------------------^
                 CHARINDEX('>, Authentication-Results', @itemProp) - CHARINDEX('Message-ID=<',@itemProp) -1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
                )
```

Note there are no spaces at the indicated positions.

Comment: Good eye but the missing space was a type error. I am still getting the same error (Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function.) even if the `@itemProp=' Message-ID=<6aasd2k4081-f6asdasc134-43asd45c-b2asd32429-a32ad410de78@comunic.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results'`